# python feedparser return only limited number of entries

Tags: python, feedparser

I'm new to feedparser and would like to retrive the full number or entries/articles from a feed.

```
myfeed = feedparser.parse(feedurl)
print len(myfeed['entries'])
```

For instance if I use

```
feedurl = 'http://www.korben.info/feed'
```

It only returns only 30 entries.
It's the same with other sites.

Why is this so limited ?

I need to retrieve the **full** list of articles URLs from a site.

How can I achieve this please ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: actually the page http://www.korben.info/feed lists 30 articles, which is what feedparser returns.
But I know here are hundreds of articles.
Is there a way to get a list of all of them ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not FeedParser related.
Feedparser gets data from the feed url.
If the feed page has 30 posts listed then the number will be 30.
Even if the site has hundreds of posts.

I need something else.